# facebook js sdk deauthorizing app still results as connected in FB.getLoginStatus

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth

I am using the Facebook JS SDK to let users connect their facebook account to my website but I ran into a weird problem.

it seems when you follow these steps:

```
- connect for the first time with your fb account, 
- authorize my app, 
- go in another tab in your browser to the facebook website, 
- remove my app, 
- go back to my website tab in your browser 
- click the connect button again
```

The FB.getLoginStatus still returns response.status as 'connected' until you refresh my website's tab, only then it shows response.status as 'not_authorized'.

even FB.login is returning response.status as 'connected' until I refresh my window (even though Im calling FB.logout before this)

Why do I need to refresh my window before it shows as 'not_authorized' and how do I go about solving this?

edit: I am using OAuth functionality

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the 'FB.getLoginStatus' response object is cached by the SDK.

If you want to solve this problem, just call FB.getLoginStatus with the second parameter set to true.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  // this will be called when the roundtrip to Facebook has completed
}, true);
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/